# Какое предложение может соответствовать схеме: "подлежащее сказуемое: подлежащее сказуемое"?

Tags: члены-предложения, синтаксис, недопустимая-метка

Какое предложение может соответствовать схеме: "подлежащее сказуемое: подлежащее сказуемое"

> Я знал: удар судьбы меня не обойдет.
>
> Семен Иванович оглянулся вокруг:
> спрятаться было негде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, это первое предложение: в нем в каждой части сложного предложения грамматическая основа представлена и подлежащим, и сказуемым. А во втором предложении первая грамматическая основа состоит из подлежащего "Семен Иванович", сказуемого "оглянулся", а во второй части есть только сказуемое безличного предложения

Comment: Спасибо,что ответили..я так думала,что нужно выбрать такое предложение,в котором обе части будут состоять ТОЛЬКО из подлежащего и сказуемого,никаких второстепенных членов.А теперь поняла в чем ошибка.